# Youtube API returning 1 video per request or errors

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-api

I created code to extract data from Youtube API search query:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser
from oauth2client import client, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI
import json

DEVELOPER_KEY = "my key"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(q, max_results=50,order="relevance", token=None, location=None, location_radius=None):

    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    search_response = youtube.search().list(q=q, type="video", pageToken=token, order = order, part="id,snippet", maxResults=max_results, location=location, locationRadius=location_radius).execute()

    videos = []

    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            videos.append(search_result)
            try:
                nexttok = search_response["nextPageToken"]
                return(nexttok, videos)
            except Exception as e:
                nexttok = "last_page"
                return(nexttok, videos)
```

when I test the function with the search query,

```
youtube_search('sport')
```

sometimes return a timeout **error**:

```
timeout: The read operation timed out
```

sometimes return ConnectionResetError **error**:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

and sometimes it return **only one video per token**:

```
('CDIQAA',
 [{'kind': 'youtube#searchResult',
   'etag': '"Fznwjl6JEQdo1MGvHOGaz_YanRU/ig3kkPiIvrPIiptur1Y1wpzbSlU"',
   'id': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': '3TJP5a3pBME'},
   'snippet': {'publishedAt': '2018-07-29T16:00:52.000Z',
    'channelId': 'UCBINFWq52ShSgUFEoynfSwg',
    'title': '20-Minute Victoria Sport Workout For Toned Abs and Legs',
    'description': "Stay strong all Summer with Victoria Sport Ambassador Lindsey Harrod's 20-minute high-impact cardio workout. Tone your whole body through circuits including ...",
    'thumbnails': {'default': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3TJP5a3pBME/default.jpg',
      'width': 120,
      'height': 90},
     'medium': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3TJP5a3pBME/mqdefault.jpg',
      'width': 320,
      'height': 180},
     'high': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3TJP5a3pBME/hqdefault.jpg',
      'width': 480,
      'height': 360}},
    'channelTitle': 'POPSUGAR Fitness',
    'liveBroadcastContent': 'none'}}])
```

I need the function to return 50 videos per request but the function is unstable (errors) or refuse to return 50 videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error and i think it is caused by the http request does not update and i solved it by building the discovery resource every single time that i called the function of the request  and it worked for me.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import time


def url_sinffer(search_word):
    api_key = "Your Api key"
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)
    print(type(youtube))
    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="id",
        q=search_word,
        maxResults=1,
        type="music"
    )
    response = request.execute()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    video_id = response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']
    url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}'
    return url
```